# Can a user with readonly access change SQL server settings

Tags: sql-server, configuration, users

Database administration is not a strong point of mine, and I was wondering if a user with read only access can change the server settings.

In their query I can see this at the beginning:

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```

I'm worried because we have been having SQL database deadlock issues and performance issue, and Microsoft say `SET ARITHABORT OFF` should be `SET ARITHABORT ON`

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site, what is the MS SQL Server version(x,y,z)?

Comment: Hi @MdHaidarAliKhan it's 13.0.4001.0 from the looks of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the settings that you have mentioned in the question requires membership in public role, which is true in almost all the cases. You may refer below screenshot from the login window:

[image: Login Properties Server Role]

Kindly refer microsoft site for both of these as below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-warnings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-arithabort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

You may also refer [article](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/08/07/sql-server-setting-arithabort-on-for-all-connecting-net-applications/) from Pinal Dave on this setting. There is another wonderful [article](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-set-options-affect-query-result-set-ansi_nulls-set-ansi_padding-set-ansi_warnings-set-arithabort/) from Mr. Ahmad Yaseen,

I hope above helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I just checked and they do have public role.
So I guess that means they have set that option to off?

Comment: Thats right and you also need to note that this is local option inside a procedure/function. Refer the link which I have provided in my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, will upvote when rep is higher :)

Comment: Remember that everyone has the public role (you can't escape it). So this is just another way to say that these commands are available to everybody. And since they are just local settings (for the session or further scoped if inside a code object), I guess the reasoning is that they don't affect the "outside world". Of course SET commands *can* affect query plans/performance and concurrency aspects, which in turn can affect others. But so can any type of code you run. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As I am not discarding anything of Mr. @Learning_DBAdmin, One thing I would like to say that as you said that Build Version is `13.0.4001.0`, which is the **`SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 1 (SP1)`**. And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017) the SQL Server 2016 `Compatibility Level Designation` is **`130`**. As per MSDN BOL documentation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3177312/sql-server-2016-build-versions) Setting ANSI_WARNINGS to ON implicitly sets ARITHABORT to ON when the database compatibility level is set to 90 or higher. If the database compatibility level is set to 80 or earlier, the ARITHABORT option must be explicitly set to ON.

Comment: Hi Md Haidar Ali Khan the compatibility level is set to 110, so should arithabort be on or is it ok to be off? THanks :)